# How to get file size from file upload services in php

Tags: php

How could I get the file size from file upload services like Rapidgator, etc. in PHP?

I tried `file_get_contents` with regex, but its useless, plus i will have to deal with every website:

mediafire,mega ....

Is there any free API To handle this? (I tried URLCHECKER but its not free)

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to check a filesize of a file from another file uploading service ?

Comment: I want to make a url saver,

Comment: Go read the source code for plowshare. It's a program that interacts with a bunch of file sharing sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned each file uploading service has its own API for finding file sizes (or possibly no API for doing such a thing).

A service like UrlChecker most likely (to the best of my knowledge) collates the APIs for as many online uploading services as it can find, and will return the file information for each of them in a table for your convenience. You can either pay to leech off their service, or you can design your own, though that will require you to write code to deal with the API for each file uploading service you want to include.

Comment: so what does revivelink.com use?

Comment: @user3798608 This service pretty much is the same - it grabs a link, and if it is a supported website (e.g. MEGA) it will grab the name of the file and give you a link to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API for it, but you can always send a request to the service and just read the headers of the response and then close the connection. Nearly all of those download services send a content-length header.